# How do you regularly take advantage of VS2010's multi monitor support?

Tags: productivity, visual-studio-2010

Although I like VS2010's multi monitor support, I seem to have too many accidental window drags, where I unsnap a window without intending to.  This behavior has made me still live in the mental model of vs200X's non-snappable windows.

1) Do you have a particular layout that works for general purpose work?

2) How have you optimised for specific scenarios (SQL, Debugging, Workflow, WPF)

3) Are you aware of any hotkey or utility that will jump to a particular window layout?

4) Are you aware of any way I can reduce the times I accidentialy undock a window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have 2 screens but I don't use VS on both of them. I prefer to keep the other screen for the application being debugged because I want to see the effects of each instruction.

Sometimes I undock 2 windows code editor and put them side by side, on the same screen, for code comparison and similar operations.

Answer (score 0):

I undock nearly everything and have one monitor that is a full screen code window and all the other little windows in the other monitor.

In earlier versions of studio I would push all the little windows to one side then stretch the container window across two monitors, but that required you to re-stretch every time the window was minimized.